# How do you upgrade tramp?

Tags: tramp

Tramp is a built in and does not seem to be in melpa, where can I install it from and is it a good idea to update to a newer version ?

Comment: What makes you think there’s a newer version?

Comment: package list tells me 2.2.13 the web site lists 2.3.3 and i have a bug which is resolved in 2.3.

Comment: Makes sense. If you can’t find it on melpa, you can always download and add the package manually.

Comment: That's what i was hoping to avoid, much nicer to have everything managed in one place instead of manual download or messing with git.

Comment: Emacs 26.1 should come out any time now, so you can use the suggested workaround while waiting for the upgrade (if upgrading is a possibility for you, of course)

Comment: well upgrading will likely depend on if ubuntu gets it in the next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are regular Tramp releases at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tramp/, the latest one is Tramp 2.3.3. This is roughly the same what Emacs 26.1 will bring.

The Tramp manual describes also how to use git for a recent snapshot, but this is for the courageous only.

Comment: is there a way to use this so it will download and update like melpa packages ?

Comment: I don't care MELPA, I use GNU ELPA. A while ago I've tried to make Tramp fit for GNU ELPA. This has stalled due to some incompatibilities between what ELPA expects and how Tramp is structured. Maybe I shall restart that work. But there are more prioritized tasks; if somebody else takes the ball I could help.

Comment: Okay thanks, first I have heard of gnu elpa i shall check it out any where that is package managed would be great to see for the above reason. I shall accept your answer as it seems the simplest way currently.

Answer (score 2):

For me the latest version appears under `*Packages*`. It is hosted at `GNU ELPA`, not `MELPA`.